# DDP message over websocket failure

Tags: c, meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm currently working on a C application sending message to a Meteor server over websocket. 
I'm using [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) for JSON conversion and [nopoll](http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/) as websocket library.

Everything is working fine in both way (sending / receiving) except when I try to send very large messages (about 15 000 000 characters). I think (I'm not sure) that the message is sent to the server so the nopoll library should not be the source of the issue. But, I'm sure that the message is not treated by Meteor as he should be, because the method (RPC) is never called.

I found that the websocket limitation is equal to the maximum value of a 64-bit unsigned value so this shouldn't be the problem.

On the other hand, I didn't found the maximum length for a DDP message even in the [DDP specification](https://gist.github.com/the0ther/10411865).

Have you any idea of the DDP limitation or other parameters that I didn't think about ?

Comment: Did you try to split the 15M packet into sub-packets?

Comment: I would like to not split data but If I have no choice, I'll do this. Have you an idea of the maximum weight that a sub-packet should have ?

Comment: I would think about putting such a large slab of data in the database (and not just one massive document, or you will just move your problem there), and then send a short message using DDP to inform the other end that the data is present.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed, but the noPoll library's `write` will probably fail for large messages. Unlike other solutions (i.e., [facil.io](http://facil.io) which I authored), they don't seem to implement a user-land socket buffer and the system's socket buffer is limited. Did you read [their documentation about handling failed `write` operations](http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/html/nopoll_core_library_manual.html#nopoll_manual_retrying_write_operations)?

Comment: I read (and implemented) this but the problem was in fact the client that wasn't reading fast enough. A flow-control resolved it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I was working on an architecture where the client and the server was on the same machine, I was not limited by the network. I think I was pushing too much informations too fast, and the socket was simply full of data.

The solution is simple : cut the data in several fragments as LPs suggests and implement flow-control.

I also found the [Mongo C driver](http://mongoc.org/) that could be another solution because I should be able to push data directly on the database as suggests Mikkel.

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: This is sadly **mistaken**. This limitation refers to a specific implementation and NOT the websocket protocol (which allows for ~[64bit message length fields](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2)). Moreover, the protocol supports fragmentation of "packets" (as implemented by both [facil.io](http://facil.io) and Node.js), essentially allowing for an unlimited message size (which is just plain useless, as you'll probably run out of memory). Please correct or remove your answer.

Comment: P.S. I'll remove the down vote as soon as I can (once the answer is updated). It's only there to point out that the information is incorrect for anyone reading this thread.

Comment: @Myst the problem was the lack of flow control (in my own code) so... I just don't understand the problem with my response.